# Python - Entering an Unspecified Amount of Arguments in a Function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I basically have this input I want to split into different variables using a function, but the problem is that some I want to split into 2 variables, some 3, etc. For example:

```
day, month, year = input("Birthday: ").split(",")
```

in this code you would input something like "1, January, 2000" and it would sort the day, month, and year into different variables, namely "day", "month", and "year". However, I want there to be an option for the "split" to not happen when the string is empty. So, I decided to make a function doing this.

For the function part, I have something like the below.

```
def splitText(input, thing1, thing2, thing3):
if input != "":
    thing1, thing2, thing3 = input.split(",")


bDay = input("Birthday: ")
splitText(bDay, day, month, year)
```

But this code has a problem, that there are only 3 "things" you can input into the arguments. I want it to be variable, where you can put 2, 3, 4, any number of arguments into the function. I've tried using "*args," but I'm just not so sure how to make that work for the rest of my code and whatnot.

Any help would be appreciated, either to fix this problem or just to complete the objective in a more efficient way :D

Comment: " I want it to be variable, where you can put 2, 3, 4, any number of arguments into the function." Why not just write the `thing1, thing2, thing3 = input.split(",")` part directly, instead of calling the function? Considering that, the way you intend for this to work, you're going to have to write out that whole list of "any number of arguments" *anyway*. Anyway, the function *cannot possibly work* the way you want it to, because assigning to a parameter *does not change the caller's argument* (which might not even have been a variable in the first place); only mutating that object will work.

Comment: "However, I want there to be an option for the "split" to not happen when the string is empty." Okay, and in that case, what should happen to the `day`, `month` and `year` variables in the calling code? Bluntly, I think you are confused, and trying to solve a nonsensical or nonexistent problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *args to take multiple parameters

```
def my_func(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, *args):  # *args takes infinite parameters
    print("Parameter1:", parameter1) # Printing parameter 1-3
    print("Parameter2:", parameter2)
    print("Parameter3:", parameter3)
    for argument in args: # For ever argument in our *args
        print('Argument:', argument) # Print the argument


my_func('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```

Answer (score 0):

[PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

using this you can unpack string containing n number of words.

```
bDay = input("Birthday: ")
*a_lst, = bDay.split(',')

#Birthday: 15,july,2000
#['15', 'july', '2000']
```

Instead of using variables, I would just use dictionary where I can dynamically assign key and value to it.

```
def splitText(a_lst):
    lst  = ['day','month','year']
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(a_lst)):

        for j in range(len(lst)):
            if i == j :
                d[lst[j]] = a_lst[i]
    return d

print(splitText(a_lst))



   #Birthday: 15,july,2000
    #{'day': '15', 'month': 'july', 'year': '2000'}

    #Birthday: 28
    #{'day': '28'}
```

Comment: The thing is that sometimes I will need 3 things, sometimes 2, sometimes 4. Is there any way I can make the number of things variable?

Comment: Instead of storing result into variables, store it into list as we are not sure about how many variables to create. You can access value from list using for loop.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: What if I were to keep my "day, month, year = input("Birthday: ") code? I don't exactly want to input one for each one of those, more so altogether.

I guess I'm really just looking for something that won't split and assign the variables a "None" value if the input is empty.

Comment: you can achieve this using `extended literable unpacking`. I have update my answer.  Hope this might help you to resolve your issue.